# Discovering eureka by a third-party application spring boot (Eureka-client)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix

I am working on an application that needs to communicate with one microservices of a cluster. I've configured all feigns client on microservice side (the one I need to communicate with) and I used it as a maven dependency on my application in order to use the feign clients.
All this works good. But I encountered some problems on my application. In fact, I've added eureka-client configuration so the application can discover eurek-server and communicate with the microservice. This works with one configuration file eureka-client.properties situated in classpath/ressources.

My question is : is it possible to use those properties in application.yml so we can specify differents values according to spring profile ?
Or create different eureka-client.properties per spring profile ?

Note that the discovering works now with one file containing :

```
eureka.name=CLIENT-NAME-SERVER
eureka.port=8761
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

And I don't want to register this application on eureka. The application is a normal spring boot application.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75132794/communication-between-two-eureka-clients-are-not-happening-using-docker-and-spri